# CLI Joomla installation

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, docker

I'm using the official [Joomla Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/joomla/) repo to (hopefully) rapidly install a Joomla docker instance for testing my component development. I copy my component over to the server and extract it. However, I need a way to complete the Joomla install *without using a web browser*. It seems like every resource on the web for "CLI installation of Joomla" is just how to extract the archive onto the server.

Is there any documented way or utility to complete the installation (which basically appears to be running the install.sql, creating a root user, and deleting the install directory) without using the web installer?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that did what I wanted so I built one. I hope this may help other Joomla devs.

https://github.com/thinkerytim/joomla-docker

This allows you to create a LAMP Docker container on your local dev machine, fully installed and with Joomla ready to roll (no need to do the Joomla setup via the web installer) and with your component installed as well. Any comments welcome on the Github repo.

Comment: Food for thought: https://3v4l.org/1PXPg  Bear in mind I didn't review your entire contribution and I am not terribly experienced with the intricacies of CLI coding.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at joomlatools/console from joomlatools team to install joomla via cli using composer installed in your container.

[joomlatools/console](https://github.com/joomlatools/joomlatools-console)